# Can't find fields i need in using Build with a Query builder

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm new to using Access, and could use some help from experts!

Here's the back ground of what i'm trying to accomplish:
I have two files which i have linked via a Query.  One is a total number of recipes detail, by ingredient.  The other is an ingredient master listing.     On the Recipes detail, i have a total number of inventory needed of the ingredient, expressed in ounces.   In the Ingredient Master, I have a "conversion factor" and Supplier Unit of Measure.    For example:  while I plan the food production based on the total number of ounces I need, i need to convert this to the total number of supplier units of measure I need to place an order for.
For example: if i need 500 ounces of bacon for production and i buy it by the pound, the conversion factor is 16 (for 16 oz in a lb), and i would divide 500/16 = 31.25 pounds of bacon i need to purchase.

I've attached a screenshot of my query.   When i try to build the calculation using the Builder, it won't let me reference the current query to select the two different table values to calculate.  I can't even see the fields of the query.   Also, this query when calculated, would Create a Table.  It's not a select to display.

my screenshot includes the
[image]
"error" which is basically that Access treats the calculation like its a parameter based query.      Can someone help me figure out this problem?

Comment: Don't show images show sql code! If you want to reference the query use its name, if table use that! The name you use is not definied (the query name starts with "qry_", the table name contains "summary"). You want a select query? then choose from query type, actual it's "make table"!

Comment: Click SELECT icon instead of MAKE TABLE.